# High SMART Data Values in Disks Application

Tags: disk

I am trying to diagnose a hard drive that sounds like it's still running when it should be relatively idle. Below is a screengrab of my /dev/sda after a test run.

[image]

The Assessment says it's "OK", but I see very high values for various Attributes, the most obvious from below being Read Error Rate and Seek Error Rate.

Which should I believe: the overall assessment of "OK", or the fact that the value far exceeds the normalized or Threshold values?

Comment: I would trust the assessment more than the raw values, which are often vendor-specific and thus not immediately interpretable. Even for the "Normalized" values it is not straightforward, I have two different disks which show a Normalized value of 100 and 200 for Read/Seek Error Rate, and they are both perfectly fine.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `grep -i FPDMA -A7 /var/log/syslog*`. Is this a desktop or laptop computer?

Comment: If my prior comment doesn't return any output, then show me `grep -i ata /var/log/syslog*`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema no output from the first command, pretty long output from the second because it's picking up "data" and "metadata" from that.

Comment: Paste the output at paste.ubuntu.com and I'll take a look at it. Is this a desktop or laptop?

Comment: @heynnema Here's the URL: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/P9dph5QYmF/ 

It seems to have calmed down now.

Comment: I see a few things. Your postfix mail transport is broken. See `systemctl status postfix`. There's some kind of "Condition check resulted in Rebuild Hardware Database being skipped". I didn't really see any disk errors, but we may not have searched for the right string. Post the entire /var/log/syslog and /var/log/syslog.1 to paste.ubuntu.com for me to look at. Is this a desktop computer or a laptop?

Comment: @heynnema sorry, you've asked several times and I didn't answer. This is a desktop. I'll get the syslog put up when I have a chance.

Comment: I suspect that you have a bad SATA cable or SATA port. Or the cable needs to be re-seated at the motherboard and the drive. Do you have any extra SATA cables? Can you re-seat the current cable?

Comment: @heynnema I'll check it when when I get the opportunity. Thank you for helping me out.